# Determine If This Is A Topology on U

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:U \to V$ be a function and supposed that $T$ is a topology on $V$.

Then {$f^{-1}(S):S \in T$} is a topology on $U$.

I understand that I need to prove this or provide a counterexample using the three conditions for a topology.

I understand that $f^{-1}(V) = U$ and $f^{-1}(empty set) = empty set$.

I do not see how to prove or disprove the other two conditions based on the available information.

Comment: Can't you express $f^{-1}(S)\cap f^{-1}(S')$ and $f^{-1}(S)\cup f^{-1}(S')$ ?

Comment: @NUG , I have the same your question but I am not sure is it true statement ?I think it is false statement since we do not know about f is continuous or not and then we cannot find f^-1(empty set)=empty set, could you please help me with that asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $$f^{-1}[\cup_{i \in I} U_i] = \cup_{i \in I} f^{-1}[U_i]$$

and $$f^{-1}[\cap_{i \in I} U_i] = \cap_{i \in I} f^{-1}[U_i]$$

for all index sets $I$ and all $U_i \subseteq V$.

The proofs of these should be easy (or else you should not be doing topology..)

Check that these imply that the inverse images of open sets in $V$ are then closed under all unions and finite intersections, because open sets in $V$ are as well.